# MySQL "max_execution_time" defaults to 30000ms when using the ODBC connector in Classic ASP, and cannot be changed

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, mysql-connector

This is an issue that has been bugging me for several months now, and one which I have yet to find a solution for.

The default `max_execution_time` when using the MySQL ODBC connector (8.0) in a Classic ASP application is set to 30000ms (30 seconds), and I can't figure out how to increase it.

I have a large table (400,000+ rows) and I'm using the `UPDATE` command to perform various calculations several times a day, usually this takes less than 30 seconds, but as the table continues to grow I'm beginning to see more and more `[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.15]Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded` errors being logged.

I keep coming across the same answers when searching for a solution:

- Set `max_execution_time = x` in `my.ini`
- Or execute `SET [GLOBAL]/[SESSION] max_execution_time = x;` before
  running a SQL command.

These solutions work fine, but only when you use a MySQL client (such as MySQL Workbench), but they make no difference when using the ODBC connector within a Classic ASP application.

The following code will always output `max_execution_time: 30000`

```all-vbs
Dim dbConn, dbRS

Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") : dbConn.Open("DSN=my_system_dsn")
Set dbRS = dbConn.Execute("SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'max_execution_time';")

Response.Write(dbRS("Variable_name") & ": " & dbRS("Value"))

dbRS.close() : Set dbRS = nothing
dbConn.close() : Set dbConn = nothing
```

Another solution that I've come across is to use:

`SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(x) */ FROM TABLE...`

But this only works for read-only SELECT statements, and not UPDATE commands.

It doesn't seem to matter what I change, whether it's in the MySQL ODBC Data Source Configuration, changes to the connection string, or the MySQL ini file, the `max_execution_time` remains at 30000ms when using the ODBC connector to access MySQL within Classic ASP.

I did find [the following bug report and discussion](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81071) on the MySQL website from 2016 where people were reporting the same issue with the ODBC 5.x connector when used with Classic ASP, but nobody was able to offer a solution.

I'm just wondering if anybody else has come across this issue and was able to find a way of increasing the `max_execution_time` value?

---

**The solution thanks to @Shadow**

```
Dim dbConn, dbRS

Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.Open("DSN=my_system_dsn")
dbConn.CommandTimeout = 120
Set dbRS = dbConn.Execute("SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'max_execution_time';")

Response.Write(dbRS("Variable_name") & ": " & dbRS("Value"))

dbRS.close() : Set dbRS = nothing
dbConn.close() : Set dbConn = nothing
```

Output: `max_execution_time: 120000`

Comment: Have you tried setting the CommandTimeout property either in the Connection or in the Command object before executing the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase the [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017) parameter of the ADO Connection or Command object before executing the query. This property configures how long the driver waits for the execution of a query.

Comment: You made my day :)

Comment: Is there a way to  configure the CommandTimeout parameter of the from the MySQL Connector/ODBC on windows (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975487/how-can-i-configure-mysql-connector-odbc-on-windows-to-set-the-readtimeout?noredirect=1#comment135699134_76975487)