# How can I configure MySQL Connector/ODBC on windows to set the readtimeout?

Tags: mysql, windows, odbc, mysql-connector

I have a query on a MySQL database on large table and am getting this error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): 
"ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.38-41-log]Query execution 
was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded"
```

I likely need to extend the max_execution time, that defaults to 30 seconds (ref. [MySQL "max_execution_time" defaults to 30000ms when using the ODBC connector in Classic ASP, and cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486689/mysql-max-execution-time-defaults-to-30000ms-when-using-the-odbc-connector-in))

Or the read time-out (ref. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html)

I want to configure this in the ODBC driver on Windows:

[image]

However, I do not know where and how:

[image]

please advise

Comment: I have not tried this, but you could try `SET @@session.max_execution_time = 180000;` in the `Initial Statement` field.

Comment: @user1191247, that did not work

Comment: What did work is adding `/*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(180000) */` to the SELCT statement (`select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(180000) */ column1, ...`). However that feels like a workaround. Is there no way the configure the `CommandTimeout` parameter of the from the MySQL Connector/ODBC on windows to set the readtimeout?